# Conditional printing of solutions in exams package

Tags: formatting, conditionals, exam

I am using `exam` package and want to print solutions conditionally. I can print solutions by using `answers` option in `exam`. I can get two lines for answers using `\fillwithlines{1.0in}` in each question. But this is a very naive approach. I wonder how can I get two lines automatically for answers if I don't want to print solutions. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints, answers]{exam}
%\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, xhfill, float}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer:}\par\noindent}


\linespread{1.4}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.2in}

\setlength\linefillheight{0.5in}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
Where does XYZ live?

\fillwithlines{1.0in}

\begin{solution}
XYZ lives in home.
\end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the environment `solutionorlines` instead of the environment `solution`?

```
%\documentclass[12pt, addpoints, answers]{exam}
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, xhfill, float}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer:}\par\noindent}


\linespread{1.4}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.2in}

\setlength\linefillheight{0.5in}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
Where does XYZ live?

\begin{solutionorlines}[1.0in]
XYZ lives in home.
\end{solutionorlines}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a similar question with beamer in normal and handout mode.

I think of the same solution with the `{subfiles}` package:

You basically create 3 files:

---

`exam-with-answers.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{your-former-main.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

`exam-without-answers.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{your-former-main.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

`your-former-main.tex`

```
\documentclass[exam-with-answers.tex]{subfile}
%% ...
```

---

you can successfully compile either one. `your-former-main.tex` and `exam-with-answers.tex` will result in containing the answeres, `exam-without-answers.tex` will have no answeres. *Plus* you get both documents with different names without any additional effort.